# Activate hover action on a certain word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

Okay, so this is something that has already been done so I know it's possible. What I'd like is that, when the user hovers the mouse on some word defined by the `wordHoverAssign()` function, something would get activated.

So, in a more concise manner: When the page is loaded the text *I love potatoes!* shows up on screen, created with HTML. Then the function `wordHoverAssign("potatoes")` is executed. What should happen then, when I hover the word *potatoes*, is that an alert message would pop up with, for example, this message *You hovered the word!*.

Is this possible? How would I go about doing it? I'd really like it if I didn't have to use any more frameworks/plugins. I'm using jQuery by the way.

Thank you.

My code so far (if you don't feel like setting it up):

```js
wordHoverAssign("potatoes");

function wordHoverAssign(theWord) {
  //code here
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>I love potatoes!</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following allows you to assign different function to any word inside the #content div. The associated function is called only when the specific word is hovered.

```
<div id="content">
    I love potatoes!<br/>
    She loves something else<br/>
    The potatoes coming again.
</div>

<script>
    window.wordsAssigned = {};
    function wordHoverAssign(word,func){
        wordsAssigned[word] = func;
    }

    wordHoverAssign('potatoes',function(){
        alert('Patatoes hovered!');
    });
    wordHoverAssign('something else',function(){
        alert('something else!');
    });

    $(function(){
        var content = $('#content');
        var html = content.html();
        for(var word in wordsAssigned){
            html = html.replace(new RegExp(word,"gm"),'<span onmouseover="wordsAssigned[\''+word+'\']()">'+word+'</span>');
        }
        content.html(html);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you may assign different functions

Comment: So, if I don't want an anonymous function to activate, but another function I had declared, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @JocaPinto instead of passing an anonymous function you simply pass the name of the desired function, like so: wordHoverAssign('word',myDeclaredFunction)

Comment: i'm sorry I wasn't completely clear. what if that function has parameters?

Comment: If it has parameters then you will have to use an anonymous function and then call your function from inside, like this: wordHoverAssign('word',function(){ myDaclaredFunction(param1, param2, etc...); });

Answer (score 1):

As per your need [:contains('text')](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) suits you better. see example:

```
wordHoverAssign("potatoes");

function wordHoverAssign(theWord) {
  $( ":contains("+theWord+")" ).hover(function(){
      alert("Hover happend");
  })
}
```

Here is [**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eyuyhvtz/1/)

---

But above code will alert twice because of hover event also bind with body, so my suggestion is use special tag. See following snippet:

```
wordHoverAssign("potatoes");

function wordHoverAssign(theWord) {
  $( "p:contains("+theWord+")" ).hover(function(){
      alert("Hover happend");
  })
}
```

Another [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eyuyhvtz/2/) for hover in `p` tag. It won't work on body hover.

Comment: It's not working I think. Where ever I hover I get the message.

Comment: I'm sorry but what I wanted was that when I hovered only the word, and not the `<p>` or `<div>` the word was in.

Comment: So you want to over only `potatoes`?

Comment: Yes its possible but not this way. Actually you can only bind event to `HTML`  element if you want to bind this hover to only `potatoes` word. You first you have to find and wrap all `potatoes` into a element like `span` then apply event to all those span.